# Is there a general form of a logical formula with N variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, closed-form, extrapolation, derivation-of-formulae

Let N = 2. Then there are 16 possible non-equivalent N variable logical formulas, listed below.

False,
A ∧ B,
¬(A → B),
A,
¬(B → A),
B,
A ⊕ B,
A v B,
¬(A v B),
¬(A ⊕ B),
¬B,
B → A,
¬A,
A → B,
¬(A ∧ B),
True.

A possible general form for N = 2 could be: (A v B) ∧ (A v B).

Each of the above formulas can be represented with the general form by simply switching logical operators. Potential derived forms are below, in order.

(A ∧ ¬A) ∧ (A ∧ A),
(A ∧ B) v (A ∧ ¬A),
(A ∧ ¬B) v (A ∧ ¬A),
(A v A) v (A v A),
(¬A ∧ B) v (A ∧ ¬A),
(B v B) v (B v B),
(¬A ∧ B) v (A ∧ ¬B),
(A v B) v (A v B),
(¬A v ¬B) v (¬A v ¬B),
(A v ¬B) ∧ (¬A v B),
(¬B ∧ ¬B) ∧ (¬B ∧ ¬B),
(A v ¬B) v (A v ¬B),
(¬A ∧ ¬A) ∧ (¬A ∧ ¬A),
(¬A v B) v (¬A v B),
(¬A v ¬B) v (¬A v ¬B),
(A v ¬A) ∧ (B v ¬B).

Is there a form like this for every N? If so, what is the smallest?

Comment: This question is about *propositional*, not *first-order*, logic, so I've retagged. Also, did you mean to put something after the colon in the penultimate paragraph?

Comment: If you just write out every possible term in sum-of-products, then you get a complete listing of the boolean function, and flipping arbitrary $\neg$s will do it.

Comment: Fixed @NoahSchweber, thanks